# libcrashpad_handler.so: library "libc++_shared.so" not found: needed by main executable

Tags: android, crashpad

I followed the manual written by [Bugsplat](https://docs.bugsplat.com/introduction/getting-started/integrations/mobile/android) to build Crashpad for Android.

The build was successful and I got all necessary libraries. However I noticed that the prebuilt library [libcrashpad_handler.so](https://github.com/BugSplat-Git/my-android-crasher/blob/master/app/src/main/cpp/crashpad/lib/arm64-v8a/libcrashpad_handler.so) in Bugsplat's sample weighs about **26Mb**. And mine is only **700Kb**.

Moreover I got errors from linker when trying to catch signals from system.

`/lib/arm64/libcrashpad_handler.so": library "libc++_shared.so" not found: needed by main executable`

Is the instructions are not up-to-date on Bugsplat? Maybe there should be some `extra_cflags` passed to `gn gen --args` ?

Btw, I tried to include c++shared into apk with:

```
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                arguments "-DANDROID_STL=c++_shared"
            }
        }
```

But i got no success to load it.

Really appreciate your assistance in building *libcrashpad_handler.so*.

Comment: Hi @bobbyg603  can you give me some advice?

Comment: Hi @sheikh, we never really solved this. One of the members on our team hacked together the version of libcrashpad_handler.so you linked to using CMake. Feel free to use it in your application. Here's a thread in crashpad-dev where we explore the problem you ran into https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/g/crashpad-dev/c/s9GmIcGsSiA. Perhaps you might start a new thread in that group? They might look into the problem if enough people run into it.

Comment: @bobbyg603, wow, i didn't expect to meet such problem in google project 
Thanks for info! Sure, I will get acquainted with the thread and ask them for help.